# Accesing state variables in an other contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I as trying to add methods in a contract, but it got so big that i couldn't deploy it with truffle. Now i need to create an otehr contract that will be called instead of the original contract to process data stored in the original contract as state variable.

The variable i am going to process is a mapping.

I am trying to do somehting like this :

```
contract Original {

mapping(bytes32 => Person) private Persons;

 /* many structs and methods here */
}

contract SecondContract {
   function processdata(){
     /* here i want to process the data stored in the mapping in the first contract */
   }
}
```

how do i get the link between the two contracts and be able to process that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplifying @Travis's answer.

This line

`Original original;`

adds considerable size to `SecondContract` because it *contains* `Original`.

That's a separate issue that can be solved with an interface. `SecondContract` doesn't require the complete bytecode for `Original`. That is repetitive and unnecessary. It only needs the function signature and address of the instance to talk to.

There are some tricky inheritance and type-casting concerns to untangle so that `SecondContract` can inherit the smallest possible representation of `Original`'s surface area (but not the working code) and both contracts can be in perfect sync about the layout of the `Person`. I decided to take a stab at it for you. You can extrapolate from that to a more complex situation.

`SecondContract` will be *much* smaller because the `interfaces` it inherits will never grow very large.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

interface Types {
  struct Person {
    uint age;
    string name;
  }    
}

interface IOriginal is Types {
  function persons(bytes32) external view returns(uint, string memory);
}

contract Original is IOriginal {
  mapping(bytes32 => Person) public override persons;
}

contract SecondContract is Types {
  IOriginal original;

  constructor(address ofOriginalContract) {
    original = IOriginal(ofOriginalContract);
  }

  function processData(bytes32 someBytes) public {
    (uint age, string memory name) = original.persons(someBytes);
    // do something with entry
  }
}
```

It would be more satisfying if `function persons()` returned a `Person` instead of the members in the `struct` but I didn't get it to work. Perhaps a kind soul will chime in with a solution for that.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to access the data stored in `Original`.
If that's the case, you can do something like this:

```
contract Original {
  mapping(bytes32 => Person) public persons;
}

contract SecondContract {
  Original original;

  function SecondContract(address ofOriginalContract) {
    original = Original(ofOriginalContract);
  }

  function processData(bytes32 someBytes) {
    Person entry = original.persons[someBytes];
    // do something with entry
  }
}
```

Notice that I made `persons` a `public` mapping, so we can access it from another contract.

Comment: That is something i did already, but the problem that i can't add anything more to my contract, because it will not get deployed on the ganache-cli (due to size). so adding a second contract next to the original contract won't be different from adding  `processData` function to the original contract

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can do it with delegatecall and assembly: enter a function's selector and it will delegatecall. U can write any logic u want in the SecondContract while it will execute in Original.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Original {
    struct Person {
        uint age;
        string name;
    }

    uint256 public x = 0;
    address public secondContract; 
    mapping(bytes32 => Person) private Persons;

    constructor(address _addr) public {
        secondContract = _addr;
    }

    fallback() external {
        bytes4 _selector;
        assembly {
            // get the function's selector
            calldatacopy(0x0, 0, 4)
            _selector := mload(0x0)
        }
        // delecgatecall: for example, u can modify 'x'
        secondContract.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(_selector)); // low level interactions input: 0x57e7c8c2
    }
}


contract SecondContract {
    struct Person {
        uint age;
        string name;
    }

    uint256 public x = 0;
    address public secondContract; 
    mapping(bytes32 => Person) private Persons;

    function processdata1() public {
        // for example, u can modify 'x'
        x = 1;
    }
    function processdata2() public {
        // do somethin u want
    }
    function processdata3() public {
        // do somethin u want
    }
    function getHash() public pure returns(bytes4){
        return bytes4(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("processdata1()"))); // 0x57e7c8c2
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.